# How to use request-mock to test custom Authentication Handlers with Requests?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-requests, requests-mock

I know I can easily use requests-mock to get calls/custom sessions calls quickly.  Now I have a custom authenticator:

```py
 class SimpsonsAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
     def __call__(self, r):
         # Implement my authentication
         r.headers['Authentication'] = "Crusty the Clown"
         return r
```

```py
>>> import requests
>>> import requests_mock

>>> with requests_mock.mock() as m:
...     m.get('http://test.com, text='resp')
...     resp = requests.get('http://test.com', auth=SimpsonsAuth())
```

When the mocked `get` doesn't raise the auth.  How do I fire off that Authentication handler?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to supply a more complete example, because as written the auth plugin will add the header every time.

```
import requests
import requests_mock

class SimpsonsAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
     def __call__(self, r):
         # Implement my authentication
         r.headers['Authentication'] = "Crusty the Clown"
         return r

with requests_mock.mock() as m:
    m.get('http://test.com', text='resp')
    resp = requests.get('http://test.com', auth=SimpsonsAuth())
    print(m.last_request.headers)
```

Prints

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Authentication': 'Crusty the Clown'}
```

Then it becomes more about how you implement your auth plugin as to how you handle the flow, doing a basic copy from [the inbuilt Digest Auth](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/6de4f104cd8813e3fb2fca6c8297211794728cad/requests/auth.py#L108):

```
import requests
import requests_mock


class SimpsonsAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpsonsAuth, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.header = None

    def handle_401(self, r, **kwargs):
        if r.status_code == 401:
            # do some stuff
            self.header = "Crusty the Clown"

            prep = r.request.copy()
            prep.headers['Autentication'] = self.header
            _r = r.connection.send(prep, **kwargs)
            _r.history.append(r)
            _r.request = prep
            return _r

        return r

    def __call__(self, r):
        r.register_hook('response', self.handle_401)

        if self.header:
            r.headers['Authentication'] = self.header

        return r


with requests_mock.mock() as m:
    m.get('http://test.com',
          text='resp',
          request_headers={'Authentication': 'Crusty the Clown'})

    m.get('http://test.com', status_code=401)

    auth = SimpsonsAuth()
    resp = requests.get('http://test.com', auth=auth)

    for req in m.request_history:
        print(req.url, req.headers)
```

Returns

```
http://test.com/ {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
http://test.com/ {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Autentication': 'Crusty the Clown'}
```